# Why does my ClientLibrary css file keep including Bootstrap?

Tags: aem

In CQ5, I've made a clientLibrary for one of my pages. Even when I remove all embed's and dependencies, the output .css file that gets loaded by my page has bootstrap at the top of the file. The client library itself just has a few js and css files that don't include or require bootstrap in any way. Am I missing something? Also I'm noticing the js file this clientLib outputs includes lot of scripts from my libraries that I'm not including in the clientLib or calling as a dependency/embed.

Below is my clientLibs .content.xml file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jcr:root 
    xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" 
    xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:ClientLibraryFolder"
    categories="[apps.myPage]" />
```

Answer (score 3):

AEM saves the compiled clientlibs in a cache. Sometimes it happens the invalidation of the cache is not triggered. With using the following url you can execute the invalidation or the rebuild of your clientlibs:

*/libs/granite/ui/content/dumplibs.rebuild.html*

Is your problem not solved check the clientlib setup at the following page.

*/libs/granite/ui/content/dumplibs.html*

This page gives you insight about the embeds and dependencies on your clientlib. Probably a the reference still exists.

Everything configured well and it still doesnt work? In that case change the jcr:nodename of your clientlib folder. Check it once again.. Does it work, change back the name and it will work ;)